# Cannot add squid module to Webmin

Tags: squid, webmin

G'day All,

I cannot find any threads on my problem which is that after much trying I cannot get the Squid module to appear in my servers list. It is installed and running and Webmin knows it is the latest version but I have no way of configuring it beside the CLI.

How do I get the module to appear if reinstalling (without errors) fails to work?  Any help gratefully appreciated.

Ta,
Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install it from the command line.  Webmin will find it then.

Cheers,